# How to reset compizComfig settins from tty1

Tags: unity, compiz

I installed CompizConfig from ubuntu software-center onto 12.04 LTS. I changed desktop, effect, general and so on settings. I am unable to open terminal after pressing Ctrl + Alt+ T. Neither close icon is shown nor open any apps dirctely.. I face problem very much.. I don't know how reset each and every settings before i set in..
When I type command amd ENTER **unity --reset** in tty1
It gives

```
WARNING:no DISPLAY variable set, setting is to :0
unity-panel-service : no process found
Backend      :  ini
Integration  :  true
Profile      :  default
Adding plugins
Initializing core option...done
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command on tty to  reset compiz,

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```

Comment: I think sometimes the compizconfig is unter .compiz. So: `rm -rf ~/.compiz`  (At least i found a .compiz directory yesterday, while cleaning up my home)

Answer (score 0):

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
unity --reset
```

Hope it helps.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html